# Splitting a xlsx/csv file based on column value

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, powershell, csv

I'm aware this question has been asked previously, but I've had no luck with previous answers. My spreadsheet has around 30000 total lines.

My spreadsheet is formatted like this:

```
Name,colour,postcode,Easting,Northing,type,Group
123,red,1,1,1,1,oscar 
123,blue,1,1,1,1,bravo
122,magenta,1,1,1,1,oscar 
122,turquoise,1,1,1,1,oscar 
121,brown,1,1,1,1,bravo 
121,green,1,1,1,1,oscar
```

I need to split the file based on the Name field. A bonus if I can split by name and group (for example all fields containing 121 & oscar in one file, etc.), but I will be very happy with splitting by name alone.

Comment: Is using a tool like ‘grep’ an option for you?

Comment: Small VBA macros (~20-30 lines of code) can do it.

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned, I only have access to standard windows tools (powershell, cmd prompt etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to split into different files:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\temp\example.csv
$names = $csv | select -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
foreach ($name in $names) { $csv | where {$_.name -like $name} | export-csv c:\temp\example_$name.csv }
```

You can do it again, replacing name with group to split each resulting file if it helps

Comment: This code works for me to some extent. It creates the files exactly as needed but overwriting with the same name (example_$name.csv). Is there a part of the code I didn't edit correctly?

Comment: `$name` should expand when running, so each file gets a unique name. Did you happen to enclose the path in single quotes or rename the variable in `($name in $names)` ?

Comment: Yes I did enclose the path in single quotes. My path has spaces so was throwing up an error when input without quotes - EDIT: Fixed with double quotes, all working! Thank you so much sir I will upvote you.

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to select it as the answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

To group the output, simply use the `Group-Object` cmdlet.

```
> Import-Csv .\example.csv | Group-Object Name,Group | Sort-Object Name

Count Name         Group
----- ----         -----
    1 121, bravo   {@{Name=121; colour=brown; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=bravo }}
    1 121, oscar   {@{Name=121; colour=green; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar}}
    2 122, oscar   {@{Name=122; colour=magenta; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar }, @{Name=12...
    1 123, bravo   {@{Name=123; colour=blue; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=bravo}}
    1 123, oscar   {@{Name=123; colour=red; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar }}
```

Please note that `Group-Object` outputs the own fixed properties `Count,Name,Group`
(not related to ***your*** property names.)
Disadvantage here is the automatically generated`Name` property containing a comma
(can't directly be used for the output file name)

But you can create a grouping on the fly similar to a calculated property.

```
>  Import-Csv .\example.csv | Group-Object {$_.Name+'_'+$_.Group.Trim(' ')}| Sort-Object Name

Count Name         Group
----- ----         -----
    1 121_bravo    {@{Name=121; colour=brown; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=bravo }}
    1 121_oscar    {@{Name=121; colour=green; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar}}
    2 122_oscar    {@{Name=122; colour=magenta; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar }, @{Name=12...
    1 123_bravo    {@{Name=123; colour=blue; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=bravo}}
    1 123_oscar    {@{Name=123; colour=red; postcode=1; Easting=1; Northing=1; type=1; Group=oscar }}
```

To ouput the groups to `speaking` file names:

```
Import-Csv .\example.csv | Group-Object {$_.Name+'_'+$_.Group.Trim(' ')} | Sort-Object Name |
   ForEach-Object{
     $File = "example_{0}.csv" -f $_.Name
     $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $File -NoTypeInformation
   }
```

Sample result:

```
> gci example_*.csv | %{'_'*10+$_.Name+'_'*10;gc $_.Name;""}
__________example_121_bravo.csv__________
"Name","colour","postcode","Easting","Northing","type","Group"
"121","brown","1","1","1","1","bravo "

__________example_121_oscar.csv__________
"Name","colour","postcode","Easting","Northing","type","Group"
"121","green","1","1","1","1","oscar"

__________example_122_oscar.csv__________
"Name","colour","postcode","Easting","Northing","type","Group"
"122","magenta","1","1","1","1","oscar "
"122","turquoise","1","1","1","1","oscar "

__________example_123_bravo.csv__________
"Name","colour","postcode","Easting","Northing","type","Group"
"123","blue","1","1","1","1","bravo"

__________example_123_oscar.csv__________
"Name","colour","postcode","Easting","Northing","type","Group"
"123","red","1","1","1","1","oscar "
```